# How to build events aggregation service for high load system with DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, events, architecture, amazon-dynamodb

I'm working on an Ad-tech system which serves millions of users.
Basically users (non anonymous users) can see different Ads that are being created by the marketing team.
Our marketing team want to be able to set some Frequency caps on those Ads (among other targeting rules they already have)

**For example:**

1. "We should not show this ad for a user if he already seen/click this ad more than X times in the last Y days"
2. Also ads can be grouped to campaigns, so rules like that are also possibile:
   "We should not show this for a user if he viewed more than X times ads in this campaign in the last Y days".

Also our marketing might wanna know how many people viewed/click a specific add in the last Y days.

We have roughly 200K RPM and our responses should be very fast.

The smallest unit of time for our queries is one day and it will not change.

**Few questions and thoughts:**

1. Is DynamoDB a good fit?
2. I thought about creating a table for each event type (Click/View/Close..)
3. What is the best way to configure the primary key?
   I thought about settings the primary key as the user id and the sort key as a combination of the ad id and the current day {dd/mm/yyyy}
4. I thought about use "ADD" operation to increase the counter when a user click/view/.. an Ad in a specific date. are they expensive operations? do I have an alternative?
5. What is the best way I can use to also be able to query per ad and campaigns as well (for example: "all users views for all ads in campaign" or "get all ad views in the last 40 days) ) ?
6. What other considerations should I take in mind?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

At the scale and latency you are talking about, I would suggest using a primary memory based datastore instead of a persistent datastore, primarily for 3 reasons:

- For one user id-ad id pair you would have very frequent count updates (as in within few days) and post the ad campaign is switched off it will not have any updates ever.
- You need counter updates as fast as possible with relatively acceptable low durability (please comment if this assumption is wrong) as in, even in case of eventuality (like a failure) you end up losing cached data and a few user sees the ad more than the frequency cap it is not end of the world scenario.
- Read and counter update will be far more common use case than queries for analysis by marketing teams. So that would be our primary area of optimisation anyway.
- For 200K RPM we have 288 million requests a day (assumed duration for the frequency cap reset). Assuming each request will produce only 1 ad and hence only one frequency cap entity we will have our daily data limited to **within 30GB** (based on each cap data less than 100 bytes) which is relatively easy to fit into a memory based datastore or cache. Again a educative guess at best.

I would suggest using **redis like main memory based datastore**, with a asynchronous backup into any database (marketing queries can be sustained by any decent database). If you have some other benefits of using DynamoDB (like you are using AWS based system already or something) definitely checkout **Dynamo DB Accelerator(DAX)** which provides similar controls. DAX provides a cache layer on DDB which will make sure you can have low latency and automatically take care of updating DDB with its latest state.

**Finally the on the keys:**

Option 1: `Partition: userId  Sort: adId-date`
However, this will make query like *how many people clicked this ad on this date* require a scan i.e. not ideal. If this is used, a secondary index is preferred with the option 2.

Option 2: `Partition: ad-id Sort: date-userId`
Unless we have too few ads and huge number of users seeing one ad (few and huge are relative, but still) this should work fine. I would prefer this over the first.